# Why does ZeroBrane studio evaluates "^" as not a number when the power is a double

Tags: lua, double, pow

Well as it generally says, I have the following situation. I wrote a "main.lua" file, which includes the other file with an object definition having the following method:

```
  function self:Process(vRef,vOut,bNeg)
    mErrO = mErrN
    mErrN = (bNeg and (vOut-vRef) or (vRef-vOut)) -- Refresh error state
    logStatus(nil,"MER= "..mErrO.." > "..mErrN)
    local errS  = getSign(mErrN)
    -- P-Term
    logStatus(nil,"S P: >> "..tostring(errS))
    local errP = mErrN;          logStatus(nil,"0 P: >> "..tostring(errP))
          errP = errP^mpP;       logStatus(nil,"1 P: >> "..tostring(errP))
          errP = math.abs(errP); logStatus(nil,"2 P: >> "..tostring(errP))
          errP = errP*errS;      logStatus(nil,"3 P: >> "..tostring(errP))
```

As you all may see, if we have like (-198^1.01), the result must be ( respectively ) (-208.75257542111). I added the following line in the "main.lua" file:

```
local a = (-198^1.01)
local b = ( 198^1.01)
local c = ( 0^1.01)

logStatus(nil,"-------------Pow: {"..a..","..b..","..c.."}")
```

However, these are calculated correctly. I thin it is somehow related by the object and the fact that the ZeroBrane must be using an older version of Lua. Strangely when the power argument is 1,2,3,4 ... It works fine. The program output is as follows:

```
-------------Pow: {-208.75257542111,208.75257542111,0}
MER= 0 > -198
S P: >> -1
0 P: >> -198
1 P: >> nan
2 P: >> nan
3 P: >> nan
```

Any answer will be appreciated !

Comment: I have the "setPower" method like this:

```function self:setPower(pP, pI, pD) mpP, mpI, mpD = (tonumber(pP) or 0), (tonumber(pI) or 0), (tonumber(pD) or 0); return self end``` Also when  I print it it prints ```Power: {P=1.5, I=1, D=1}``` I notived the option to use the Lua interpreter 5.2 and 5.3, but the one that I am using does not have a version next to it, so I may asume the it is Lua 5.0 ( I may be wrong though )

Comment: "lust" I believe you meant "must". Should probably edit the post ;)

Comment: Done, though this error is so weird... It drove me nuts ```(-198^1.01 == nan)```

Comment: Can you update the question with a script that can be run without any additional functions (`logStatus`, `getSign`)? Also, it's not clear what parameters you use when you call `Process` function.

Comment: I've tested this in both lua 5.1 and lua 5.3 and I've gotten the same results. As aditional test case, `(-198 + 0) ^ 1.01` also returned `-nan`. I expect this to be a bug in lua, but I can't confirm that, so I'm not posting it as an answer. By the way, @ДеянДобромиров This is a lua thing and has nothing to do with zerobrane!

Comment: @DarkWiiPlayer - `(-198 + 0) ^ 1.01` is nan because of `log(-198)` does not exist.  Raising to power has higher priority than negation, so `-198^1.01` is not nan.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff how do you get from (-198 + 0) ^ 1.01 to log(-198)? I don't get it. doesn't (-198 + 0) ^1.01 evaluate to -198^1.01? Share your wisdom please :)

Comment: @Piglet - Sorry, it's just my guess that `pow` is using `log` and `exp`.  I don't know how `pow()` is implemented in "math" C library. Whatever, it can not calculate `(-198)^1.01` anyway :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first code

```
local errP = mErrN;     -->  -198
      errP = errP^mpP;  -->  nan
```

the expression being calculated is `(-198)^1.01`.
It is `nan` according to [math definition of raising to power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Real_exponents_with_negative_bases) and according to the man page of `pow()`:

> pow(x, y) returns a NaN and raises the "invalid" floating-point exception for finite x < 0 and finite non-integer y.

In your second code

```
local a = (-198^1.01)
```

the expression is `-(198^1.01)` according to [Lua operators precedence](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.4.8).
This expression equals to -208.75...

---

Probably you would want to calculate `math.abs(x)^y * (x<0 and -1 or 1)` instead of `x^y`